# How can I temporarily attach anti-bird spikes to a window air conditioner?

Tags: air-conditioning, installation, mounting, weather-resistant, duct-tape

I'm trying to stick on anti-pigeon spikes on top of my window air conditioner and want a non-permanent solution that I can take off when I put it into storage.

Is there something I can use that's weather-proof but also removable at the end of the season?

Comment: Hook and loop systems (often called by the brand name *Velcro*?

Comment: Yo magnets, yeah!

Comment: Silicon Caulk works great

Comment: superglue super magnets to the bird strips; super easy.

Comment: I'd be a bit concerned about magnets wearing through the paint due to vibration. Maybe use some vinyl sheeting between.

Comment: @isherwood: good point, but sheeting can trap dust and debris over time, turning it to sandpaper. only thing I can think of that won't do that are hotglue or rubber-cement "landing pads", which tend to seal well around the edges.

Comment: hotglue might be a good choice if the outside is not baking in the sun: you can remove it with a hair drier.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't object to a product with an analogue in hook and loop tape, but more durable and substantially stronger, consider to locate 3M Dual Lock tape. It's available in various widths and lengths as well as different adhesive types. The strongest stuff has a gel type of adhesive, not quite foam, but squishy in a fashion.

The pieces are not "gendered" as with hook and loop. The tape has tiny stalks with mushroom heads that engage the other mushroom heads (get your mind out of the 60s here!) to form a very strong bond. The adhesive is weather resistant but I'm not so sure about sun resistance.

You'd attach one piece to the spike and one piece to the cleaned surface of the air conditioner.

The magnet idea is a good one, as you'd need only one magnet if your air conditioner has a steel casing.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd bond the spikes permanently to something heavy as a base, like nylon blocks, using screws or whatever. I'd then apply rubber feet to the blocks and simply set them on the air conditioner.

No need to rely on tenuous adhesive connections and no need to replace the fastener each season.